# OpenCart 3.0.3.1 - how to display SKU on product pages

Tags: opencart-3

I have followed the instructions as per the following link:
[OpenCart 3.0.2.0 - how to display SKU on category & product pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409794/opencart-3-0-2-0-how-to-display-sku-on-category-product-pages)

Please see the excerpt below:

For Product page:

**Step 1:** Open file catalog/controller/product/product.php

Find:

```
$data['heading_title'] = $product_info['name'];
```

Add after:

```
$data['sku'] = $product_info['sku'];
```

**Step 2:** Open file: catalog\language\en-gb(your language)\product\product.php

Find:

```
$_['text_model']               = 'Product Code:';
```

Add after:

```
$_['text_sku']               = 'SKU:';
```

**Step 3:** Open file: catalog/view/theme/default(your theme)/template/product/product.twig

Find:

```
<li>{{ text_model }} {{ model }}</li>
```

Add after:

```
{% if sku %}
<li>{{ text_sku }} {{ sku }}</li>
{% endif %}
```

---

My problem arose at STEP 3:

By doing the change as recommended in STEP 3 I noticed no change in the FrontEnd.

I then opened the following file:
catalog/view/theme/theme_name/template/product/product.tpl

and directly below the following line:

```
<span><?php echo $text_model; ?></span> <span class="value"><?php echo $model; ?></span><br />
```

I added the following code:

```
<span><?php echo $text_sku; ?></span> <span class="value"><?php echo $sku; ?></span><br />
```

---

I now see SKU on the product page as follows:
SKU: SKU

Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: After change clear cache through admin panel

Comment: Please refresh ocmod cache and twig cache & then check it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61520968/opencart-3-system-cache-cleaning-ocmod-and-twig-i-made-changes-in-controller/61524855#61524855